# building golang using your docker image

Tags: docker, go, jenkins

Good day everyone. I'm in the middle of a task using our docker image to build go microservice. To reduce build time, keep the images under control.

I expect that after downloading the golang image from the docker hub, upload it to our registry and use it in all the dockerfiles of our microservices.

As soon as I started building go mircoservice, during the installation phase go gave me an error:

```
11:04:16 [91m / bin / sh: go: not found
11:04:16 [0mThe command '/ bin / sh -c go install -mod vendor' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I tried to install go in a container, write $ PATH for go, but nothing helped. Then I was told that this image already contains go.

Here are the complete build steps:

```
11:04:15 Step 1/7 : FROM 192.168.0.8:5000/golang
11:04:15  ---> 49f356fa4513
11:04:15 Step 2/7 : EXPOSE 80
11:04:15  ---> Using cache
11:04:15  ---> 6e0c49e600e6
11:04:15 Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /go/src/autocomplete-trains
11:04:15  ---> Using cache
11:04:15  ---> 41cccfb1ed82
11:04:15 Step 4/7 : COPY . .
11:04:15  ---> 1a44653382a8
11:04:15 Step 5/7 : RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
11:04:15  ---> Running in c13b5cfbfd0b
11:04:16 Removing intermediate container c13b5cfbfd0b
11:04:16  ---> ab03d13e5984
11:04:16 Step 6/7 : RUN go install -mod vendor
11:04:16  ---> Running in b3727493f938
11:04:16 [91m/bin/sh: go: not found
11:04:16 [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c go install -mod vendor' returned a non-zero code: 127
11:04:17 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM 192.168.0.8:5000/golang
    
EXPOSE 80
    
WORKDIR /go/src/autocomplete-trains
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
    
RUN go install -mod vendor
    
ENTRYPOINT ./script.sh
```

*Note: If `FROM 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine` is changed to `FROM golang` then everything works (but we don't wish to rely upon dockerhub so this is not a viable solution).*

The process used to push the image into our repository was:

```
sudo docker pull golang
sudo docker tag golang:latest 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine
sudo docker push 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine
```

Comment: can you paste dockerfile of "192.168.0.8:5000/golang", why not use "FROM golang" directly?

Comment: @suiwenfeng, We used golang directly until this error appeared
"Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit"
I added dockerfile to the body of the question

Comment: Took a quick look on my system and image id `49f356fa4513` is Alpine:3.13.4 so it looks like `192.168.0.8:5000/golang` is returning the alpine image rather than golang (I'm guessing you pushed the wrong image).

Comment: @Brits, 
I downloaded an image from docker hub and alpine, it gives exactly the same error. I'll try a couple more options, then I'll write what came of it

Comment: @Brits, Yes, I downloaded the image again, started the build, the error is the same

Comment: @DanilaMylnikov so you are downloading the alpine image and pushing it yo your registry as `golang`? (the alpine image will not have go installed so what you are seeing would be expected). Does it work if you replace `192.168.0.8:5000/golang` with `golang`? Please provide more detail on what you are pushing to your registry.

Comment: @Brits, Good day, Yes, I just download the golang: latest image, tag it with our registry, and then push it to the registry.
I substitute a new source into the dockerfile from where I need to download the image.
Basically I put the following commands in the registry: sudo docker pull golang;
sudo docker tag golang: latest 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine;
sudo docker push 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine.
If you change 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine to golang, it will work, because the image will be downloaded from the docker hub again

Comment: This appears to confirm that the issue with your registry (you are not getting the correct `golang` image). What digest do you get when you run `docker pull 192.168.0.8:5000/golang` and `docker pull 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine`?

Comment: @Brits, If I execute the command "sudo docker pull golang" then the image download will start from the docker hub, not from our registry.
Loading from our registry will only be in the case of "sudo docker pull 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine"

Comment: Not sure what led to your comment - I was asking for the digests returned by `docker pull 192.168.0.8:5000/golang` and `docker pull 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine` both of which refer to your registry. In addition please clarify what you have in your docker file (in the question it states `FROM 192.168.0.8:5000/golang` but you are now using a tag `192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine` confusingly, based on the process you gave for the `push`, you are not using the Alpine based image)

Comment: @Brits, Go projects started to build for me, I just downloaded a new golang image, made sudo docker tag golang: latest 192.168.0.8:5000/golang;
sudo docker push 192.168.0.8:5000/golang.
I went to collect the project, he got ready)
Thanks for your help, most likely there was a problem when I was doing "FROM 192.168.0.8:5000/golang" but in fact I had version 192.168.0.8:5000/golang:1.15.5-alpine in my register

Comment: No worries - glad it's working now. Checking the digests is always worthwhile (if the digest from your registry does not match that from docker hub then you are not getting the image you expected). I'm pretty sure your registry was returning the `Alpine:3.13.4` (raw alpine, go not installed) image rather then the golang image.